# Creating with java a CloudFront signed url with getSignedURLWithCustomPolicy instead getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy

Tags: java, url, amazon-cloudfront, signature

Please take a look of the following code:

```
public static void ok() throws InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {
    String privKeyStr = "/path/to/aws/aws-cloudfront-key-pair/pk-APKAJV4KUNWFL43EMJNA.pem";
    File privKey = new File(privKeyStr);

    String url0 = CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy(
        Protocol.https,                  // protocol
        "example.com",                   // distributionDomain
        privKey,                         // privateKey
        "ok.mp4",                        // objectKey
        "APKAJV4KUNWFL43EMJNA",          // keyId
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000*60*60*24) // endDate
    );

    String url1 = CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCustomPolicy(
        Protocol.https, 
        "example.com", 
        privKey,
        "ok.mp4", 
        "APKAJV4KUNWFL43EMJNA", 
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000*60*60*24), // end date
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000*60*60*24), // begin date
        "0.0.0.0/0");

    System.out.println(url0);   // This url works perfectly well: it lets me view the video
    System.out.println(url1);   // This does not !!! WHY ????? : it says: access denied
}
```

When using "getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy" i get a functional url that works as expected. However, when I use "getSignedURLWithCustomPolicy" which, by the way is almost identical, it does not work and I get "Access Denied" from Cloudfront.

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: The Policy in the resulting URL is a JSON document, encoded in base64, then the characters `+` `=` `/` are transliterated to `-` `_` `~` (to avoid URL escaping issues).  Reverse that process and you can inspect the JSON and the problem may become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue - in my case it was fixed by providing IPv6 address instead of IPv4. I spot it when I ran curl -vvvv aws_url.